# force footer bottom with responsive design

Tags: html, css

I have a footer that only stick to the bottom when the page is long, but if the page is too short the footer sticks at the middle of the page. I have seen a few methods where they set `margin:0 auto -180px;` in a `.wrapper` class. However this can be a problem since my footer height change depending on resolution (responsive design). also setting the `.footer` class `position:fixed;` and `bottom:0;` works, but it then overlap the content of the long pages.

My footer is not 100% done and I'm planning on making each of the `.item` classes side by side on big screens but below each other on smaller screens like phones. This will make the footer height even longer which is why I have a problem setting the height `.footer` height and `.wrapper` margin "static".

css:

```
.footer {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#23282c;
    position: relative;
    margin:auto;
    min-height:180px;
    z-index:15;
}

.footer-bottom-wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
}
.footer-bottom {
    background-color:#1e2327;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:25px;
    color:#777f8c;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:25px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:9;
}



.item {
    position:absolute;
    left:220px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.i1 {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    padding-top:7px;
    margin-left:-210px;
    padding-right:190px;
    font-size:15px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.i2 {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    padding-top:7px;
    margin-left:-150px;
    padding-right:190px;
    font-size:15px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.i3 {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    padding-top:7px;
    margin-left:-150px;
    font-size:15px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.item h1 {
    color:#fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #475f93;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:left;
}

.item .p {
    color:#777f8c;
}

.footer-link {
    color:#777f8c;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

.footer-link:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
```

wrapper and body CSS:

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
html { overflow:auto; height:100%; }
body { background-color: #e9ebee; margin:0; padding:0; font-size:10px; cursor:default; height:100%; }
body, html {font:13px "open sans",sans-serif;  overflow-x:hidden;}

/* Base Styles
********************************************************************* */
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #e9ebee;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  
}
```

footer.php:

```
<footer class="footer" id="footer">

    <div class="item i1">
        <h1>Subscribe</h1>
        <div class="p">
            <form method="POST" action="/assets/php/subscribe.php">
                <label>Subscribe to our newsletter!</label><br />
                    <input type="email" class="footer-input" name="sub-email" placeholder="E-mail">
                
                <div style="margin-top:5px;"></div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="btn" name="subscribe" style="width:100%;"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    

    <div class="item i2">
        <h1>Help</h1>
        <div class="p">
            Need any help?<br />
            You can find a help page<a href="/help" class="footer-link">here</a>.
        </div>
    </div>

    
    <div class="item i3">
        <h1>Server</h1>
        <div class="p">
            About our server
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="footer-bottom-wrapper">
        <div class="footer-bottom">
            <div class="fl">
                <a class="footer-link" href="/help">Help</a>    |
                <a class="footer-link" href="/ads">Advertise</a>    |
                <a class="footer-link" href="/Rules">Rules</a>  |
                <a class="footer-link" href="/Terms-Of-Service">Terms Of Service</a> |
                <a class="footer-link" href="/credit">Credits</a>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-fr" style="padding-right:10px;">&copy; Copyright <?php echo $domain; ?> | 2015 - <?php echo date("Y") ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

    <!-- Script that requier bottom! -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/script/notification.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/script/level-bar.js"></script>


<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){ ?>
      </div>
<?php }else{ ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You should Google _Flexible Height Sticky Footer_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often use a sticky footer which is `position: absolute;` with a fixed height (e.g. `height: 120px;`) in desktop mode. The content area get a `padding-bottom` accordingly to the footer height to prevent overlap.

In mobile mode the footer change from `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;`, and the height is now `height: auto;`. The `padding-bottom` must be removed from the content area also.

```
#content {
    padding-bottom: 120px;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #content {
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    #footer {
        position: relative;
        top: auto;
        left: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

**Basic Example:**

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#page {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#header {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
#content {
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #content {
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  #footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: auto;
    left: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="#content">small content</div>
  <div id="footer">footer content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: After testing this on both my computer and phone, it apears that this is the best solution. I already have a css where I change classes depending on resolution so i can easly add this there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a min-height of html and body:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Is *footer* a direct child of *body*?

Comment: nope, didint work. tried it with both `position:relative;` and `position:fixed;` but neither worked

Comment: OP needs a flexible-height sticky footer.

Answer (score 0):

What I tend to do is use `position:fixed;bottom:0;` and then add `margin-bottom:footerHeightInPixels;` to whatever the last element on the page is.

As you mentioned, you want to have things shift about with different sized viewports. You could make this work by using mulitple stylesheets for each screen size. E.G.

`<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 980px)' href='small.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 981px)' href='big.css' />`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your css may it's help you.

```
 html {
        min-height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    .footer_box {
        bottom: 0;
        height: 70px;/*according to your height */
        position: absolute;
        width:100%;
        background-color:#23282c;
        position: relative;
        margin:auto;
        min-height:180px;
        z-index:15;
    }
```

Comment: same problem as before, it sticks to the bottom (just like giving fotter a fixed position and bottom:0;) but overlap the .wrapper class